# Acces FormArray in Angualr in nested FormArray?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

Having a `FormArray` inside another `FormArray` ho can i access the second FormArray?

This is what i have in my component:

```js
registrationForm = new FormGroup({
    registrations: new FormArray([this.patchRegistrationValues()])
  });

patchRegistrationValues(): FormGroup {
    return new FormGroup({
      //some other FormControls
      setDate: new FormArray([this.patchSetDate()]),
    });
  }

get registrations(): FormArray {
    return this.registrationForm.get('registrations') as FormArray;
  }
```

How do i access `setDate` to populate it? I tried this but did not work:

```js
get setDate(): FormArray {
    return this.registrations.get('setDate') as FormArray;
  }
```

Does anyone now how to do it? Do i actually need an index?

### UPDATE

Sory for the late reply, this is my html:

```html
<thead>
    <tr>
        <!-- TODO: add translation to table -->
        <th>Project</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Buttons</th>
        <th nzAlign="center" class="fit">
            <app-add-btn (click)="addRegistrationRow()" label="{{'common.add' | translate}}"></app-add-btn>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody formArrayName="registrations">
    <tr *ngFor="let reg of registrations.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
        <td>
            <!--FormControl goes here like an input-->
        </td>
        <td>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let date of setDate.controls let ind = index" [formGroupName]="ind">
                <!--Not so shure about this part, any input i set here doesn't show in the page is like a blank cellulare-->

            </ng-container>
        </td>
        <td nzAlign="center" class="fit">
            <app-delete-btn (click)="removeRegistrationRow(i)"></app-delete-btn>
            <app-add-btn (click)="addSetDateRow()" label="{{'common.add' | translate}}"></app-add-btn> <!-- this doesn't work -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Sorry again for being late!

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the index to the parent FormArray.

```js
getSetDateControlFromRegistrationForm(registrationIndex: number): FormArray {
  return (this.registrations.controls[registrationIndex] as FormGroup)
    .get('setDate') as FormArray;
}
```

Doubt that by providing the index as a parameter, you can't apply the method as a getter.

---

**Update**

Based on the attached HTML template, so what you need are:

1. A wrapper for `formArrayName="setDate"`
2. Iterate `setDate` FormArray control(s) with the method provided above.
3. Most inner part will be the FormGroup and its FormControl(s).

```
<ng-container formArrayName="setDate">
  <ng-container
    *ngFor="
      let date of getSetDateControlFromRegistrationForm(i).controls;
      let ind = index
    "
  >
    <!-- Form Group in each setDate Form Array -->
    <div [formGroupName]="ind">
      <input formControlName="i" />

      <input formControlName="date" />
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1gfvv1?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: So in my html how would i cycle through the FormArray if i can not use getter function?

Comment: Would be great if you can provide the HTML template. For me, getter is ** a kind of method**, without getter, you still can able to achieve by calling the method.

Comment: I've updated the question with more informations!

Comment: Done update the answer. This may meet your requirement.